# How to get installation path during uninstall?

Tags: installation, inno-setup

My idea is to offer the user the choice of installing the application either in `{localappdata}` or `{commonappdata}`, and that part works fine. However, I'm using custom Inno Setup skinning support, which requires a couple functions to get loaded during installation/uninstallation.

I have a `DefaultAppDataFolder(): String` function which returns the folder that the user chose (either common or local appdata one), and it works fine during installation. However, when I try to uninstall the app, it throws following error right upon execution:

> Script error: Could not call proc

You can see that in the `DefaultAppDataFolder()` function I'm getting the uninstall directory in a bit shady way, extracting the file directory twice from the `{UninstallExe}` constant, maybe there is a better way to retrieve this?

Here is my script:

```
#define ApplicationName "MyApp"
#define ApplicationExe "app.exe"
#define ApplicationInstanceMutex "APPMUTEX"
#define InstallerFilename "install_app"
#define SkinName "Carbon.vsf"

[Setup]                                                                               
AppName={#ApplicationName}
AppVerName={#ApplicationName}
DefaultDirName={code:DefaultAppDataFolder}
DefaultGroupName={#ApplicationName}
UninstallFilesDir={code:DefaultAppDataFolder}\uninstall
UninstallDisplayName={#ApplicationName}
Compression=lzma2     
SolidCompression=yes
OutputDir=.\
DisableDirPage=yes
OutputBaseFilename={#InstallerFilename}
UninstallDisplayIcon={code:DefaultAppDataFolder}\{#ApplicationExe}
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
AppMutex={#ApplicationInstanceMutex}
WizardImageFile=installer_images\installer-1.bmp
WizardSmallImageFile=installer_images\installer-2.bmp

[Files]
Source: "skins\VclStylesInno.dll"; DestDir: "{code:DefaultAppDataFolder}"; Flags: uninsneveruninstall ignoreversion
Source: "skins\{#SkinName}"; DestDir: "{code:DefaultAppDataFolder}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "root_files\*.*"; DestDir: "{code:DefaultAppDataFolder}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "client_files\*.*"; DestDir: "{code:DefaultAppDataFolder}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "ssl_libs\*.*"; DestDir: "{code:DefaultAppDataFolder}"; Flags: ignoreversion

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\{#ApplicationName}"; Filename: "{code:DefaultAppDataFolder}\{#ApplicationExe}"; WorkingDir: "{code:DefaultAppDataFolder}"
Name: "{group}\Uninstall"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}"
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#ApplicationName}"; Filename: "{code:DefaultAppDataFolder}\{#ApplicationExe}"; Tasks: desktopicon

[Run]
Filename: "{code:DefaultAppDataFolder}\{#ApplicationExe}"; Description: "Launch {#ApplicationName}"; Flags: postinstall nowait runascurrentuser

[Tasks]
Name: commondir; Description: "&All users"; GroupDescription: "Install For:"; Flags: exclusive
Name: localdir; Description: "&Current user"; GroupDescription: "Install For:"; Flags: exclusive unchecked
Name: desktopicon; Description: "Create a &desktop icon"

[Code]
procedure LoadVCLStyleS(VClStyleFile: String); external 'LoadVCLStyleW@files:VclStylesInno.dll stdcall setuponly';
procedure UnLoadVCLStylesS; external 'UnLoadVCLStyles@files:VclStylesInno.dll stdcall setuponly';

procedure LoadVCLStyleU(VClStyleFile: String); external 'LoadVCLStyleW@{code:DefaultAppDataFolder}\VclStylesInno.dll stdcall uninstallonly';
procedure UnLoadVCLStylesU; external 'UnLoadVCLStyles@{code:DefaultAppDataFolder}\VclStylesInno.dll stdcall uninstallonly';

var
  ApplicationUninstalled: Boolean;
  WizardInitialized: Boolean;

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
var
  C1: Integer;
begin
  ExtractTemporaryFile('{#SkinName}');
  LoadVCLStyleS(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\{#SkinName}'));
  result := TRUE;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  WizardInitialized := TRUE;
end;

procedure DeinitializeSetup();
begin
  UnLoadVCLStylesS;
end;

function InitializeUninstall(): Boolean;
begin
  LoadVCLStyleU(ExpandConstant('{code:DefaultAppDataFolder}\{#SkinName}'));
  result := TRUE;
end;

procedure InitializeUninstallProgressForm();
begin
  ApplicationUninstalled := TRUE;
end;

procedure DeinitializeUninstall();
begin
  UnLoadVCLStylesU;
  UnloadDLL(ExpandConstant('{code:DefaultAppDataFolder}\VclStylesInno.dll'));

  if ApplicationUninstalled then
  begin
    DeleteFile(ExpandConstant('{code:DefaultAppDataFolder}\VclStylesInno.dll'));
    RemoveDir(ExpandConstant('{code:DefaultAppDataFolder}'));
  end;
end;

procedure CurUninstallStepChanged(CurUninstallStep: TUninstallStep);
var
  mres: integer;
begin
  case CurUninstallStep of
    usPostUninstall: begin
      mres := MsgBox('Do you want to delete user data?', mbConfirmation, MB_YESNO or MB_DEFBUTTON2)
      if mres = IDYES then
      begin   
        DelTree(ExpandConstant('{localappdata}\{#ApplicationName}'), TRUE, TRUE, TRUE);
        DelTree(ExpandConstant('{userappdata}\{#ApplicationName}'), TRUE, TRUE, TRUE);
      end;
    end;  
  end;
end;

function DefaultAppDataFolder(Param: String): String;
begin
  if IsUninstaller then
    result := ExtractFileDir(ExtractFileDir(ExpandConstant('{uninstallexe}')))
  else
    if (WizardInitialized) and
       (IsTaskSelected('localdir')) then
      result := ExpandConstant('{localappdata}') + '\Programs\{#ApplicationName}'
    else
      result := ExpandConstant('{commonappdata}') + '\Programs\{#ApplicationName}';
end;
```

Comment: You should install to `{userpf}`.  It's not really sensible to offer a choice between `{commonappdata}` and `{localappdata}`.

Comment: Right, `{userpf}` seems to be equivalent to `{localappdata}\Programs`. But what if I want to give an option to user to install app for all users on the system?

Comment: Then you give them a separate installer.  You can't do both things in one script, because they require different privilege levels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you got is not related to the uninstaller; you can narrow the problem down to this:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName=My Program

[Code]
procedure DoSomething;
  external 'DoSomething@{code:GetLibPath}\MyLib.dll stdcall setuponly';

function GetLibPath(Value: string): string;
begin
  Result := 'C:\ValidPathToLib';
end;
```

From the above script it seems that you cannot use scripted constants for imported DLL file names. And even delayed loading didn't workaround this limit. But for your case you can use just `{app}` path since your library is actually there (if I get your intention right):

```
...
procedure LoadVCLStyleU(VClStyleFile: string);
  external 'LoadVCLStyleW@{app}\VclStylesInno.dll stdcall uninstallonly';
procedure UnLoadVCLStylesU;
  external 'UnLoadVCLStyles@{app}\VclStylesInno.dll stdcall uninstallonly';
...
```

Comment: Yes, you got it right there. However, this only works if i install app in `{commonappdata}` dir, and doesnt work if i install it in `{localappdata}` dir. When I run uninstaller, it says: "Cannot import dll:<utf8>C:\ProgramData\Programs\App\VclStylesInno.dll", which means `{app}` _always_ refers to `{commonappdata}` dir for some reason. I put MsgBox() in DefaultAppDataFolder() and it looks like it isnt even executed before error, so I have no clue where it got this dir from??

Comment: What is interesting is that even when I select to install it to {localappdata} dir, it creates blank {commonappdata}\Programs\App directory.

Comment: For me it's very difficult to reconstruct your project. But I would start with refactoring of the script; e.g. the `DefaultAppDataFolder` function is overused. I would personally use it just for setting `DefaultDirName` directive value and on the all other (possible) places use just `{app}`.

Comment: Since I skip DirPage, I believe {app} is getting initialized only once, at start of installer/uninstaller, and it points to {commonappdata} directory. So I can't really use {app}, but we're getting closer to the solution now, I would somehow need to change DefaultDir variable (WizardForm.DirEdit.Text), after Tasks form, I believe? However, that won't solve uninstallation problem.

Comment: Yep, that did the trick. I set WizardForm.DirEdit.Text in PrepareToInstall() callback, and it works perfectly even for the uninstaller. Here is the full script: http://pastebin.com/X2EvSSE5. Thank you for pointing me in right direction! If you edit your answer to explain this, I would accept it too, so it serves as useful reference to further readers.

Comment: Yes, to set an `{app}` folder manually you're correctly assigning value to `WizardForm.DirEdit.Text`. About a post edit, what do you want to explain specifically ? I've tried to spot just on the error and how to workaround it (because that error is quite hard to decode and if you would focus only on that error in your question, it would become even more useful, I think).

Comment: Yeah, I guess that is fine as well, it answers my question properly (although the problem was elsewhere). Accepted.